# Programa em C encerra após execução de procedimento

Tags: c

Boas,
É o seguinte, estou a desenvolver um programa que é para avaliação, que consiste em fazer uma gestão de medicamentos...o objetivo é ter as funcionalidades de adicionar e remover medicamentos, assim como a sua listagem...
Estou com o problema que ao escolher a listagem o programa lista tudo bem....mas encerra de seguida.
Aqui está o excerto de código, obrigado.

```
    int main(){
      setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

      char *categorias[20] = {"Anti-Infeciosos", "Sistema Nervoso Central", "Aparelho Cardiovascular", "Sangue", "Aparelho Respiratório",\
                                    "Aparelho Digestivo", "Aparelho Geniturinário", "Doenças Endócrinas", "Aparelho Locomotor", " Medicação Antialérgica",\
                                    "Nutrição", "Corretivos da Volemia", "Afeções Cutâneas", "Afeções Otorrinolaringológicas", "Afeções Oculares",\
                                    "Antineoplásticos", "Intoxicações", "Vacinas", "Meios Digestivos", "Material Diverso"};

      char *viasAdministracao[10] = {"Oral", "Injetável", "Dermatológica", "Nasal", "Oftálmica", "Respiratória", "Auricular", " Sublingual",\
                                     "Intramuscular", "Retal"};
      int nMedicamentosInserido = 0;
      char opcao;
      struct medicamentos medicamento[2000];
      int armario [20][10], bit[20][10][10];
      int nr;

      do{

    printf("\n\n\t FARMÁCIA\
              \n1 Administração\
              \n2 Venda de Medicamentos\
              \n3 Listagem de Medicamentos\
            \n\n4 SAIR");
    printf("\n\nInsira uma opção: ");
    scanf(" %c",&opcao);

    switch (opcao) {

      case '1':{
        printf("\n\n1 Inserir medicamentos\
                  \n2 Gerir medicamentos fora de validade\
                  \n3 Inserir sócio");
        printf("\n\tInsira uma opção: ");
        scanf(" %c",&opcao);

        if(opcao == '1'){

          int categ, viaz;

          printf("\nInsira a sua categoria: ");
          scanf(" %i",&categ);
          fflush(stdin);

          printf("\nInsira a via de administração: ");
          scanf(" %i",&viaz);
          fflush(stdin);

          nr= (categ * 100) + (viaz * 10);

          if(armario[medicamento->categoria][medicamento->viaAdministracao] != 10){
          inserirMedicamento(&medicamento[nr + armario[medicamento->categoria][medicamento->viaAdministracao]], armario, bit, nMedicamentosInserido, categ, viaz);
          //nMedicamentosInseridos = nMedicamentosInseridos + MEDICAMENTO.quantidade;
          printf("\n%s",medicamento[nr].nomeMedicamento);

          nMedicamentosInserido++;


        }
        }
        break;
      }

      case '2':{
        vendaMedicamento(&medicamento[nr - armario[medicamento->categoria][medicamento->viaAdministracao]], armario, bit, categorias, viasAdministracao, nMedicamentosInserido);
        break;
      }

      case '3':{
        printf("\n\n1 Listagem de todos os medicamentos\
                  \n2 Listagem por categoria\
                  \n3 Listagem por via de administração\
                  \n4 Listagem por data de validade");
        printf("\nInsira uma opção: ");
        scanf(" %c",&opcao);

        if(opcao == '1'){
        listagemMedicamentos(medicamento, categorias, viasAdministracao);
        }
        if(opcao == '2'){
        listagemCategoria(medicamento, categorias, viasAdministracao, nMedicamentosInserido);
        }
        if(opcao == '3'){
        listagemVia(medicamento, categorias, viasAdministracao, nMedicamentosInserido);
        }
        if(opcao == '4'){
        listagemData(medicamento, categorias, viasAdministracao, nMedicamentosInserido);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }while (opcao != 0);
  return 0;
}


    void listagemMedicamentos(struct medicamentos* medicamento,char* categorias[], char* viasAdministracao[]){
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 2000; i++){
      if(medicamento[i].validade.mes != 0){
                 printf("\n\n\tNome: %s\n\tCategoria: %s\n\tVia de administração: %s\n\tData de validade: %i/%i/%i\n\tQuantidade: %i\n\tPreço: %1.f",\
                        medicamento[i].nomeMedicamento, categorias[medicamento[i].categoria], viasAdministracao[medicamento[i].viaAdministracao], medicamento[i].validade.dia,\
                        medicamento[i].validade.mes, medicamento[i].validade.ano, medicamento[i].quantidade, medicamento[i].preco);
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Não sou especialista mas não falta um system("pause"); após a exibição dos dados?

Comment: Acontece o mesmo :/

Comment: Posta o seu main e a rotina completa. Você incluiu a  biblioteca stdlib.h? Você pode tentar assim também : printf("Pressione ENTER \n");
getchar();
return 0;

Comment: ja postei, nao inclui vou exprimentar obrigado :)

Comment: não resultou :/

Comment: Bom, a 10 anos atrás era desses dois jeitos que eu fazia ou usava o  getchar para forçar esperar uma operação de entrada e saida do usuário (E/S) ou usava o system pause para forçar o programa a aguardar. Se optar por system("PAUSE"); tem que incluir a biblioteca stdlib.h o método é nativo dela. Outra coisa essa função não deveria ter um return. E por último edita a sua pergunta a identação ficou muito bagunçada pouco se entende. Mas um detalhe está rodando em linux se estiver usar o getchar system("PAUSE") é para windows DOS.

Comment: nao se trata de uma função e sim um procedimento.Obrigado pela opinião vou mudar o titulo. Estou a fazer em windows

Answer (score 0):

Como estão aí apenas excertos do código, não tem como rastrear tudo, mas se não recebe uma mensagem de erro, é porque há um problema de lógica.

Seu input diz que para sair o usuário insere 4 e armazena isso na variável opção, mas no final do bloco do {} while ele diz para repetir enquanto opção for diferente de 0, ou seja, seu programa não tem condição de saída.

Você reusa a variável opção durante os cases 1 e 3, e testa essa variável fora do escopo do case no do {} while, gerando comportamento não previsto.

É provável que em algum momento esteja atribuindo o valor 0 à opção, e isso leva o programa a encerrar quando chega no fim do do {} while.

Recomendações: Use uma variável de controle diferente para cada controle de fluxo. Cada switch deve ter sua variável. Evita esse tipo de erro.

Eu não gosto de do {} while, porque separa o marcador do bloco da condição de repetição, mas é válido.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda. essa parto do do while foi lapso meu a condição já corrigi, vou seguir  a sua recomendação, qual recomenda ao invés do do while?

Comment: Em vez de `do { código } while condição` prefiro `while condição { código }`, principalmente para blocos grandes como este.